# How to override binding in subling child submodules in scala play

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I have scala play multimodule application with 3 modules: common, moduleA and moduleB where moduleA and moduleB depend on common.
ModuleA and moduleB should bind different implementation for trait defined in common.

If I try to bind it this way:

```
class ModuleA extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[Foo]).to(classOf[ModuleAFooImpl])
  }
}

class ModuleB extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[Foo]).to(classOf[ModuleBFooImpl])
  }
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
1) A binding to Foo was already configured at ModuleB.configure(ModuleB.scala:11) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> ModuleB).
```

Foo is used in ActionBuilder in common submodule in this way:

```
class CustomAction @Inject()(foo: Foo) extends ActionBuilder[Request]{
override def invokeBlock {
   ...
   case Left(_) => Future.successful(foo.onUnauthenticated())
   ...
}
}
```

I've tried to used named binding, like this:

```
bind(classOf[Foo]).annotatedWith(Names.named("ModuleAFoo")).to(classOf[ModuleBFooImpl])
```

but it didn't work.

Does anyone know if it's possible to bind different implementations for the same trait in two subling submodules?

Comment: But.. does moduleA and moduleB are used at the same time ? ModuleA should not even see the code of moduleB. I don't understand how you can get such error.

Comment: Yes. They are used at the same time. These are 2 different parts of the application, one used by administrators, the other one used by regular users. They share some parts of the code, which exists in common module, such as authentication, but each module has specific routes referred from the shared code. That's why I need different implementations for the same trait

Comment: Guice injection works at runtime, not at compile time, thus if at runtime there are both moduleA and moduleB this explains the error. You should probably bind by name then, or even by directly to the subclass rather than the trait. Any specific reason to bind to the trait?

Comment: Sorry missed the thing about `CustomAction`: there will be a single instance at runtime: it cannot work with two different implementations. You need 2 different custom actions.

Comment: I've updated CustomAction in original question to give you a bit more of context how I'm using it. I've tried to make CustomAction abstract and have named implementations in both modules. Also, I've tried to bind by name Foo in each module. The problem with both approaches is that it requires so much changes across the whole application that I've eventually gave up. Almost every controller in both modules is using CustomAction

Comment: I was hoping that I can find some more elegant way to inject different routes for /unauthorized and /unauthenticated in common for each module without affecting too much each controller.